# Jquery issue sending data to php

Tags: php, jquery, charts, drop-down-menu, get

I am working at a project for my school but I have an issue with my code.
Explanation: I made a dropdown menu which is populated from my DB which is working fine. In the dropdown are all "workstations" with their "ID" so when I select a station I am sending it via the GET method to my data.php file which than creates a json file with all the data from the selected workingstation and with that data I create several charts. The problem is that whatever workstation i choose it shows me only the predefined station(Station 1).

This is the jquery code which takes the dropdown value and puts it in the var dropd which then gets send to the data.php file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    var dropd = $("#drop").val();
    console.log(dropd);
    $.getJSON('data.php', {id: dropd});
      function grab() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

grab().then((data) => {
    console.log('Recieved our data', data);
    let Zeit = [];
    let Luft = [];

    try {
        data.forEach((item) => {
            Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
            Luft.push(item.Luftfeuchtigkeit);
        });

        let chartdata1 = {
            labels: [...Zeit],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Luftfeuchtigkeit',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                data: [...Luft]
            }]
        };

        let ctx = $("#myChart1");

        let barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata1
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error);
    }

}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Here is my data.php file that creates the json file for my charts.

```
 <?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usera01");
$id = isset($_GET['dropd']) ? $_GET['dropd'] : false;
   if ($id) {
      //echo ($_GET['dropd']);
   } else {
     $id = 1;
   }

$sqlQuery = "SELECT idDatenNr, Luftfeuchtigkeit, Lichtverhältnis, Bodenfeuchtigkeit,Temperatur, Zeit, fi_idStation FROM daten WHERE fi_idStation = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}

mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Sorry if it looks a bit messy but i am quiet new to jquery and php. Thank you.

Here is my full code for the charts including the select.

```
<select id ="drop">
  <option disabled selected>--Wähle Station aus--</option>
  <?php
    $records = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idStation, Stationname FROM station WHERE fi_idFirma = $id");
      while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
       {
         echo "<option value='".$data['idStation']."'>" .$data['Stationname']."</option>";
       }
  ?>
</select>
           <button id="button1">Lade Tabelle</button>
<div>
<canvas id="myChart1"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
<canvas id="myChart3"></canvas>
</div>
<div>
<canvas id="myChart4"></canvas>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    var dropd = $("#drop").val();
    console.log(dropd);
    $.ajax({ url: "data.php", method: "GET", data: { id : dropd }, success: function(data) { }, error: function(error) { reject(error); } });
      function grab() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

    grab().then((data) => {
        console.log('Recieved our data', data);
        let Zeit = [];
        let Luft = [];

        try {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
                Luft.push(item.Luftfeuchtigkeit);
            });

            let chartdata1 = {
                labels: [...Zeit],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Luftfeuchtigkeit',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: [...Luft]
                }]
            };

            let ctx = $("#myChart1");

            let barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata1
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error);
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
function grab() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

    grab().then((data) => {
        console.log('Recieved our data', data);
        let Zeit = [];
        let Boden = [];

        try {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
                Boden.push(item.Bodenfeuchtigkeit);
            });

            let chartdata2 = {
                labels: [...Zeit],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Bodenfeuchtigkeit',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: [...Boden]
                }]
            };

            let cty = $("#myChart2");

            let barGraph = new Chart(cty, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata2
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error)
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
    grab().then((data) => {
        console.log('Recieved our data', data);
        let Zeit = [];
        let Temp = [];

        try {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
                Temp.push(item.Temperatur);
            });

            let chartdata3 = {
                labels: [...Zeit],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Temperatur',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: [...Temp]
                }]
            };

            let ctt = $("#myChart3");

            let barGraph = new Chart(ctt, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata3
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error);
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
function grab() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
                resolve(data);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

    grab().then((data) => {
        console.log('Recieved our data', data);
        let Zeit = [];
        let Licht = [];

        try {
            data.forEach((item) => {
                Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
                Licht.push(item.Lichtverhältnis);
            });

            let chartdata4 = {
                labels: [...Zeit],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Lichtverhältnis',
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                    hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                    data: [...Licht]
                }]
            };

            let cte = $("#myChart4");

            let barGraph = new Chart(cte, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata4
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error)
        }

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

And here is what my debugger tells me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing id from the ajax that's why you are only getting the id = 1 from the else part in php. Try sending data through ajax.

$.ajax({
url: "data.php",
method: "GET",
data: { id : dropd },
success: function(data) {
},
error: function(error) {
reject(error);
}
});

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#button1").click(function(){ 
    var dropd = $("#drop").val(); 
    console.log(dropd);
    $.ajax({ url: "data.php", method: "GET", data: { id : dropd }, success: function(data) { }, error: function(error) { reject(error); } });` But it is not working sorry for the layout i dont know how to edit it propperly i am new to stackowerflow.

Comment: check what are you sending to php file in debugger tool.

Comment: I think I know where the Problem is but i dont know how to solve it . In the Debugger he sends the value but then he send three times nothing i will post my whole code where the 4 charts are in and a photo from my debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand, but I migth be wrong, it seems that when you call the function `$.getJSON` you do nothing with the result, because you close the function with semicolon before doing something with the result and then you make another call with AJAX sending no ID and in your PHP since `$id` is not set, it enters the else and $id takes the value of ***1*** . Let me explain in comments

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    var dropd = $("#drop").val();
    console.log(dropd);
    $.getJSON('data.php', {id: dropd});//You finish the statement but never did anything with the results.
      function grab() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({//Here you make another request but you never send the ID
            url: "data.php",
            method: "GET",
            success: function(data) {
            },
            error: function(error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Since probably the first `console.log()` you have, did print something; you assumed you did send it to the server, and you did, on `$.getJSON` but never did anything with the result, and then you made another petition with `$.ajax` but you never sent the ID in this case.

So try this

```
$(function () { //This is a shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){}); recommended by JQuery itself
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        var dropd = $("#drop").val();
        console.log(dropd);
        $.getJSON('data.php', {id: dropd}, function (data) {
            grab(data);
        }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            //Do something in case of fail
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            console.log( "Request Failed: " + err );
            //console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error);
            /*
             It'll enter here if the Data cannot be parsed or it any other network error occurs
             */
        });
    });
});

function grab(data) {
    console.log('Recieved our data', data);
    let Zeit = [];
    let Luft = [];

    data.forEach((item) => {
        Zeit.push(item.Zeit);
        Luft.push(item.Luftfeuchtigkeit);
    });

    let chartdata1 = {
        labels: [...Zeit],
        datasets: [{
                label: 'Luftfeuchtigkeit',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.75)',
                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(200, 200, 200, 1)',
                data: [...Luft]
            }]
    };

    let ctx = $("#myChart1");

    let barGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: chartdata1
    });
}
```

Try that or check what I told you first, and as an advice, I always use a "flag" in my JSON responses to know if all data was correctly received by PHP, for example

**Everything below here is just extra**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","usera01");
$id = isset($_GET['dropd']) ? $_GET['dropd'] : false;
   if ($id) {
      //echo ($_GET['dropd']);
   } else {
     echo '{"success":false, "message":"No ID value was received."}';
     die();
   }

$sqlQuery = "SELECT idDatenNr, Luftfeuchtigkeit, Lichtverhältnis, Bodenfeuchtigkeit,Temperatur, Zeit, fi_idStation FROM daten WHERE fi_idStation = '$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlQuery);

$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
 $data[] = $row;
}
$myJSON = ["succes": true,
"data"=>$data];
mysqli_close($conn);

echo json_encode($myJSON);
```

I mean thats an extra, but thats how you validate your inputs coming from the client, and if you need to send `$id=1` by default during a first load or something, you should do it with JavaScript and consider it an Error in PHP if not received.

In case that helps you just need to modify the $.getJSON function

```
$.getJSON('data.php', {id: dropd}, function(response){//I changed the name
        if(response.success){
            grab(response.data);
        }else{
            console.log(response.message);
        }
    }).fail(function(){
        //Do something in case of fail
        console.log('Error parsing JSON data', error);
        /*
         It'll enter here if the Data cannot be parsed or it any other network error occurs
        */
    });
```

Comment: Hello, first thank you for your reply i pasted the whole code now there you can see that i screwd up because i have in total 4 charts an every time when i click on submit it send the first time the value but than also loads(I think) 4 time something else without data in it i posted also an image from the debugger where you can see it. But thank you for the $getJASON I'm changing it now

Comment: Could you tell me what you're returning from the DataBase, like the JSON object?
The JavaScriot code is a bit confusing you're repeting the `grab()` function several times, maybe we could optimize, but I need to know what the JSON object looks like